# Merge 2 Meteor JS Projects Together

Tags: javascript, css, meteor

smart and great coders. I'm sure my question would be resolved via SO. I saw a project on GitHub which solves 30% of the coding I'll do based on the project I'm presently working on I do not want to rewrite it since this would defeat the time saving I'll trying to achieve. Running these projects separately would defeat the purpose so I'll need to adapt/integrate the project into my existing project. My question if how do I since it's a relatively large project.

Comment: we need more info. is this GH project a framework? if so, then that implies one kind of use. if it's just an app, that implies something different. also, what is its license, are you even allowed to use this code for your purposes? there's no straightforward set of steps here, it's types of solutions depending on the circumstances.

Comment: http://www.crowducate.me/ This is the web version of the project,  the code is on GitHub.  I don't have an access to my desktop now. I'm doing this on my mobile phone.Though mine is local on my system. It's a school portal. It is open source so it could be used. This project would take care of everything that has to do with creating and managing courses.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, it is project dependent and there is no 'single' answer to merge them. You need to find out how the project fits into your own, and then you can start copy-pasting stuff and creating files/folders/directories as needed.

Use git merge and resolve the conflicts manually. If your project doesn't work on the same things, conflicts would be less, but you still need to be sure to track all the new files created so you can fix and debug if anything breaks.